# Show that $\forall y \in X$ the equation $x= y + Tx$ has a unique solution

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

**Exercise :**

> Let $X$ be a Banach space, $T \in B(X)$ which means that $T$ is a bounded linear operator $T : X \to X$. We suppose that for all $y \in X$ the series 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\|T^ny\|$$
>   converges. Show that for all $y \in X$, the equation $x = y + Tx$ has a unique solution.

**Attempt/Thoughts :**

Since $X$ is Banach then the space $B(X)$ of all the bounded operators from the Banach space $X$ to $X$, is also Banach. This means that $T_n \to T$ as $n\to \infty$ over $B(X)$.

Since the given series is convergent, this means that :

$$\Bigg|\sum_{n=k+1}^\infty\|T^ny\|\Bigg| < \epsilon $$

Also, since $T$ is a bounded operator, this means that :

$$\|Ty\| \leq M \|y\|$$
**I really do now know how to use the given facts to yield a result. Any given hints or elaborations will be greatly appreciated !**

Comment: Try to arrive at "$\frac 1{1-T}=1+T+T^2+T^3+\ldots$"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Hi, thanks a lot for your comment ! I see this is the geometric series in case of $|T| <1$. How would I get to a solution using this, though ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formally, $x$ would be given by
$$ x "=" (1-T)^{-1} y$$
where by the formula for a geometric series, we should have
$$ (1-T)^{-1} "=" \sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n $$The content of the exercise is to prove that this makes sense. If we let $x_N :=  \sum_{n=0}^N T^n y $ then the given assumption implies that $x_N$ converges in $X$ to some $x:=\sum_0^\infty T^n y$, and moreover
$$(1-T)^{-1}y := \sum_{n=0}^\infty T^n y$$
is a bounded map in $B(X)$. Then just compute (since $T\in B(X)$)
$$ (1-T) x  =  \lim_{N\to\infty }(1-T) x_N = \lim_{N\to\infty} y - T^{N+1}y = y$$
Its also the case (with a similar proof) that for any $y$ of the form $y=(1-T)x$,
$$(1-T)^{-1} y = x.$$
This proves that $1-T$ is invertible, and uniqueness follows.

Comment: All in all it makes sense *but*, how do we think of $x$ as $x = (1-T)^{-1}y$ when $Tx$ is $T(x)$ ? Also, shouldn't it be $|T| <1$ or $\|T\|<1$ so that the geometric series hold ?

Comment: @Rebellos Sorry, I don't understand your first question, the fact that $Tx = T(x)$ is purely notation. Can you try to rephrase? The convergence of the series for every $y$ implies this inequality for the operator norm of $T$. (You may find the inequality $\|T^n\| \le \|T\|^n$ useful)

Comment: The expression $Tx = T(x)$ means that $x$ is the argument of the operator $T$. How come you can "solve" for $x$ like it's an ordinary quation (as $T\cdot x$), this is what I am asking.

Comment: @Rebellos Well, you shouldn't be able to without proof. This is that proof.

Comment: I get the concept now. Sorry for the questions, but this is the first time during both our course and my self study, that I handle something like this, so it took me some time (and your explanation) to grasp over the though process !

Comment: @Rebellos don't apologise for asking, glad you got it

Comment: Sorry for poking again, how would that similar proof be carried out for the final part of any $y$ of the form $y=(1-T)x$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85880/discussion-between-calvin-khor-and-rebellos).